# Deleting by ROWID

Tags: oracle, rowid

I'd like to run this query.

```
DELETE FROM A006873.GC_CLIENTS
WHERE ROWID = '14519';
```

But I get this error:

> SQL.sql: Error (2,15): ORA-01410: invalid ROWID

I got in **GC_CLIENTS**

```
ID      NUMBER      NAME
14519   0000017690  VILLAVINE
```

I don't realize what's wrong if I'm in the correct ID.
I'm using a sequence by the way and I don't want to delete it with a `WHERE ID = '14519'`.

Comment: What does `SELECT ROWID FROM GC_CLIENTS WHERE ID = '14519'` return?

Comment: What does using a sequence have to do with it? Assuming ID is a primary key, deleting by ID or ROWID will do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROWID is a psuedocolumn that returns the address of the row.

You can try this if you dont want to delete by Id

```
delete from A006873.GC_CLIENTS
WHERE ROWID in (select rowid from A006873.GC_CLIENTS where id = '14519');
```

Comment: Thanks man, that helped a lot. I'd like to learn more about Oracle, do you know a good book? or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

ID = 14519 not ROWID. ROWID is an internal identifier used to locate the value

```
SQL> select rowid from t.d;

ROWID
------------------
AAAVqIAAEAAAAInAAA
AAAVqIAAEAAAAInAAB
AAAVqIAAEAAAAInAAC

SQL> delete from t.d where rowid = 'AAAVqIAAEAAAAInAAA';

1 row deleted.

SQL> select rowid from t.d;

ROWID
------------------
AAAVqIAAEAAAAInAAB
AAAVqIAAEAAAAInAAC
```

What you want is just

```
DELETE FROM A006873.GC_CLIENTS
WHERE ID = 14519;
```